# SQL Algorithm Trouble - for loop to add and filter results

Tags: .net, sql, search

I am struggling yet again with SQL with my search function.

Basically I want a stored proc that splits up a string into words then for each word I want to check using Full Text Search if it is in any of 2 tables.

If results are found in these tables it should add them to any results it found for the other words and return a set where the record is in both these sets.

So here is my algorithm

```
if null return all restaurants

declare results = empty

for each word
if in restaurant.name or cuisine.name
    addRowsToResults 
else if in restaurant.city
    addRowsToResults 
else if in restaurant.postcode
    addRowsToResults 


addRowsToResults 
results = (results + new results) where a match is in both
```

I have no idea where to start with this and I have searched google for ages but being a begginer in SQL I may be missing some terms.

Also is this even the best way to do this sort of thing?

Appreciate any help.

**Edit:**
Just to give more info. City, Postcode and Name are all nvarchar fields in a Restaurants table. Cuisine name is in a different table and is linked through another table to restaurants as a restaurant can serve many types of cuisine.

All these fields have full text search indexing.

Comment: You want "AND", or "OR"?  You state "AND", but that would mean that the search word would have to be in the restaurant, cuisine, city AND postal code fields.  So for all of those restaurants named "21201" in "21201", MD (zip code "21201") that serve "21201" for dinner, that would be right on...

Comment: you don't really need fulltext for postcodes and plain old index will work. also you are using fulltext for something it was not designed for, it was designed to index big chunks of text, not for 2,3 words.

Comment: I want to first check if the word is in restaurant name or cuisine (as a restaurant may be called Best Chinese for example) and if no match I want to check if the word is in city, if still no match I want to check if it is in postcode. 

This is so the results are filtered as the user types words into a text box.

Comment: You are right, I could just use like for postcode. This was because I originally set it so that I just passed the words to containstable and checked all fileds. But that is not how the filtering should actually work.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't really the way SQL works.  You can get some of that same functionality, but it won't look anything like what you are asking; you are writing (naturally enough) in a more procedural style.

For one thing "add results" is trying to bring (presumably) disparate things together into a single collection.  You are - I think - asking for restaurants and cuisines and cities and postcodes all to go into the same collection, and the only kind of collection SQL has (roughly speaking) is tables, and within a table, all rows have the same type.

But maybe restaurants and cuisine and city and postcode are all fields of the same table?  Well, then, for a given word you could say

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table
WHERE  restaurant like "%" + word + "%"
OR     cuisine    like "%" + word + "%"
OR     city       like "%" + word + "%"
OR     postcode   like "%" + word + "%";
```

It starts to get complicated when you want to match multiple words; this answer is intended as a starting point; maybe once you're more familiar with SQL you can ask easier-to-answer questions.  Good luck!

**Update** based on your table descriptions

```
SELECT r.*
FROM       restaurant r
INNER JOIN link       k ON k.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
INNER JOIN cuisine    c on c.cuisine_id    = k.cuisine_id
WHERE  r.restaurant like "%" + word + "%"
OR     c.name       like "%" + word + "%"
OR     r.city       like "%" + word + "%"
OR     r.postcode   like "%" + word + "%";
```

And don't worry about which records come back "first".  Your database will be fast enough that that should not be a concern.

Comment: That is somethign similar to what I had before but the thing I am trying to do is match multiple words inputed in any order. Hence the order of my if statements in my pseudo code. 

Cuisine is the only field in a different tabe as it is linked through another table as a restaurant can serve many types of cuisine

Answer (score 1):

There is a split to words [function here](http://www.madprops.org/blog/T-SQL-to-Split-a-varchar-into-Words/). Which returns a table you can join into.

You should also investigate metaphone or soundex, but to support that you will need to pre-index your data in a separate table or pre-calc the methaphone or soundex codes for each word in a separate field and index that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your attempting to take a procedural approach to a set-based declarative query language.

First of all, you can split a string into a resultset using a table-valued user defined function. Something like the following will do -

```
CREATE function [dbo].[csl_to_table] ( @list nvarchar(MAX) )
RETURNS @list_table TABLE ([id] nvarchar(20)) -- set this to your maximum size string
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE     @index INT,
                @start_index INT,
                @id nvarchar(20)  -- set this to your maximum size string

    SELECT @index = 1 
    SELECT @start_index = 1
    WHILE @index <= DATALENGTH(@list)
    BEGIN

        IF SUBSTRING(@list,@index,1) = ','
        BEGIN

                SELECT @id = SUBSTRING(@list, @start_index, @index - @start_index) 
                INSERT @list_table ([id]) VALUES (@id)
                SELECT @start_index = @index + 1
        END
        SELECT @index  = @index + 1
    END
    SELECT @id = SUBSTRING(@list, @start_index, @index - @start_index )
    INSERT @list_table ([id]) VALUES (@id)
    RETURN
END
```

Then using your resultset, you can join to the tables that you wish to query for matches, and return a resultset of matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a split function that has an optional parameter of a delimiter...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]( @List VARCHAR(4000), @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ',' )
    RETURNS @Result TABLE (item VARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(100)
        WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,0) <> 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Item = SUBSTRING(@List,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,0)-1)
                , @List = SUBSTRING(@List,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,0)+1,LEN(@List))

            IF LEN(@Item) > 0
                INSERT INTO @Result
                    SELECT @Item
        END
        IF LEN(@List) > 0
            INSERT INTO @Result
                SELECT @List
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Then your query could look something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      'restaurants' AS [source]
    , r.ID AS [ID] --Assuming ID is your primary key column
    , r.name + '(' + r.city + ', ' + r.state + ')' AS [Description]
FROM restaurants AS [r]
JOIN [dbo].[fnSplit](@Query,' ') AS [terms]
ON
    ISNULL(r.name,'')
    +','+ISNULL(r.city,'')
    +','+ISNULL(r.postcode,'') LIKE '%'+terms.item+'%'

UNION SELECT DISTINCT
      'cuisine' AS [source]
    , r.ID AS [ID] --Assuming ID is your primary key column
    , r.name AS [Description]
FROM cuisine AS [r]
JOIN [dbo].[fnSplit](@Query,' ') AS [terms]
ON
    ISNULL(r.name,'') LIKE '%'+terms.item+'%'
```

The **fnSplit** function breaks your query terms into rows in a table variable and returns it.  The select queries then joins against the resultant table.  The query is distinct so that only 1 instance of a row is returned regardless of how many terms are matched in the query.  The join condition could easily be broken into a series of AND/OR conditions but I think LIKE operations are more expensive than concatenation so I'm just concatenating the columns.

**UPDATE**

The following simplified query can be used since Full-Text Indexing is enabled.

```
DECLARE @Phrase VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @Phrase = item + '" OR "' FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@Query,' ')
SET @Phrase = SUBSTRING(@Phrase,0,LEN(@Phrase)-6)


SELECT DISTINCT
      'restaurants' AS [source]
    , r.ID AS [ID] --Assuming ID is your primary key column
    , r.name + '(' + r.city + ', ' + r.state + ')' AS [Description]
FROM restaurants AS [r]
WHERE
    CONTAINS(r.name,@Phrase)
    OR CONTAINS(r.city,@Phrase)
    OR CONTAINS(r.postcode,@Phrase)

UNION SELECT DISTINCT
      'cuisine' AS [source]
    , r.ID AS [ID] --Assuming ID is your primary key column
    , r.name AS [Description]
FROM cuisine AS [r]
WHERE CONTAINS(r.name,@Phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I wanted to, I couldn't give you the full story on this - you haven't posted the table definitions or any sample data.

That said, I'll make some guesses. I think first of all that you need to use SQL in a set-based manner. Don't think in terms of processing row by row - process a set. Then combine the sets together.

Comment: I have updated my question to include some more info on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a For Each loop in SQL most SQL dialects have Cursors that allow you to select all of the records using some query and then iterate over the records by using a Cursor.

Comment: True, but as several replies stated, it's usually better to use the set-based features of the database rather than cursors.

Answer (score 0):

To use fulltext search you want to use the CONTAINS keyword. Look up how to use it in Books online  (I have to get to a meeting or I'd provide an example).

Comment: Yeah I've got the query using ContainsTable. I will look at the code again tomorrow, got client stuff tonight ;(